# Add background color and border to table row on hover using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Does anyone know of a way to add a border to a table row with a different background color  when the mouse hovers over the row?

I've been able to change the background color of the row with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {
        $('.actionRow').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        });
    });
});
```

But I'm unable to add a border color. I realize borders can't be directly applied to a table row tag, but I'm hoping someone know some jQuery voodoo magic that can find the table cells within the selected row and apply some styles to those to create the border.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
   $(function() {
        $('tr').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFF99');
            $(this).contents('td').css({'border': '1px solid red', 'border-left': 'none', 'border-right': 'none'});
            $(this).contents('td:first').css('border-left', '1px solid red');
            $(this).contents('td:last').css('border-right', '1px solid red');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $(this).contents('td').css('border', 'none');
        });
    });
```

Comment: It's a little squirrely in IE7.  Figures.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would be to addClass and removeClass on the row.
Then in your stylesheet:

```
.actionRow-hovered td { border-color: whatever; }
```

So you will actually be manipulating each of the td border colors instead.
A pain, but works well enough when you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table.tblMenuTabls tr').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('tblOverRow');
        },function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('tblOverRow')}
    ).css({cursor: 'hand'});
```

Where `tblMenuTabls` is the table class name and `tblOverRow` is CSS class with hover definition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a good starting point:

http://www.devcurry.com/2009/02/change-table-border-color-on-hover_27.html

Comment: That's for the whole table border, not the individual rows.