# How to set background color in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

How to set background color of `td` in jQuery?

e.g `$(this).css({**BackgroundColor:Red**})`

Thanks

Comment: Adjunct to the various answers below: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 318, accepted):

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 69):

You actually got it. Just forgot some quotes.

```
$(this).css({backgroundColor: 'red'});
```

or

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```

You don't need to pass over a map/object to set only one property. You can just put pass it as string. Note that if passing an object you cannot use a `-`. All CSS properties which have such a character are mapped with capital letters.

Reference: [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do: $(this).css({background-color: color}): wondering why it wasn't working. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 16):

How about this:

```
$(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
```

Related post: [Add background color and border to table row on hover using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688222/add-background-color-and-border-to-table-row-on-hover-using-jquery)

Comment: The # got me ^^.

Answer (score 6):

Try this for multiple CSS styles:

```
$(this).css({
    "background-color": 'red',
    "color" : "white"
});
```

Comment: You can add the animate attribute on callback function, or use animate.css library for more animations styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your attribute on callback function ({key} , speed.callback,
like is

```
$('.usercontent').animate( {
    backgroundColor:'#ddd',
},1000,function () {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor","red")
});
```