# How to set text background color using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

this is my code

```
$("#textbackground").click(function() {

        var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    ![enter image description here][1]
    //alert("weight");
    if (!obj) return;

    obj.setTextBackgroundColor('rgb(0,200,0)');

    canvas.renderAll();
    });
```

i have to do set the background color to text only, following like this link , but i am getting background color to text in square, not for text only
[enter link description here](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/)

so how do i set the

```
obj.setTextBackgroundColor('rgb(0,200,0)');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set background color in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780670/how-to-set-background-color-in-jquery)

Comment: You should include the fact that this is in fabric.js, and you're  trying to set the color of text in a canvas, not just regular text, as all the answers are wrong.

Comment: @adeneo , not all the answers :)

Answer (score 9):

Use `fabric.Object` **[set(key, value)](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#set)** function.

```
obj.set('backgroundColor', 'rgb(0,200,0)');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

if (obj.isType('text')) {
    obj.textBackgroundColor = "#ccc"; // or obj.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Try with `.css()` of property `background-color` like

```
obj.css('background-color', 'rgb(0,200,0)');
```

Or you can give the color directly like

```
obj.css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: This is for jQuery, not FabricJS