# jQuery detect background color of a fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a white menu button that has a fixed position. I have a section on my website that has a white background color. My goals is that when the menu button scrolls over the white section it turns black instead of white.

I just have no idea how I can detect the background color of my fixed element? Is this even possible?

here's what my jQuery looks like:

```
$color = how to detect bg color?;

if ($color == "#fff"){
    $("nav-icon2").css("color", "#000");
}else{
    $("nav-icon2").css("color", "#fff");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set background color in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780670/how-to-set-background-color-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working fiddle based on this solution : 
[How to get the background color code of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element)

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8jvgctn/)

```
var color = '';
var x = $(".nav-icon2").css('backgroundColor');
hexc(x);
alert(color);

function hexc(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    color = '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

**EDIT :**

If I understand correctly your issue, you wants this :

[See this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8jvgctn/4/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 350){
    $("h2").css('color','#f00');
  }else{
        $("h2").css('color','#fff');
  }
});
```

Comment: For some reason I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined' in my console

Comment: This is the correct answer related to the OP's question, because the user **is comparing the value to #fff**, hence the regex is necessary. +1 (also, a further edit should be that the user needs to compare it to #ffffff instead in this case)

Comment: @VincentG Can I do the same thing in jQuery?

Comment: @FrankLucas: did you copy the function first?

Comment: @briosheje Yes I did

Comment: I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" complaining about the first line of the function

Comment: but this answer is javascript not jquery?

Comment: Please show your code in another JSFiddle so we can help you with more efficiency.
jQuery is a javascript library so jQuery IS javascript ;)
However the hexc function is made with javacript not jquery functions

Comment: jQuery **is** a javascript library. are you passing the correct parameter to the hexc function? just copy what Vincent did, it must work.

Comment: how about give a background-color value on your #nav-icon2 ? ;)

Comment: @VincentG It doesn't have a bg color and is not supposed to have one :(

Comment: My goals is to detect the bg color of the element it scrolls over

Comment: Meh, anyway, if you don't like the function, here is a jquery plugin using Vincent's function: https://jsfiddle.net/s8jvgctn/2/ .

Comment: I don't think you guys understand. My element doesn't have a bg color. It's fixed and scrolls over all my other content. And I want the section where it scrolls over a white color it turns black

Comment: http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/ an example what I am trying to create with my menu button

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

```
var $color = $('nav-icon2').css('background-color');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
$color = $( "your-element" ).css( "backgroundColor" );
```