# Hover table in ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, hover, ascx

I have a table with some rows in an ascx-Control.

How can I add a hover-effect for a row for changing backgroundcolor or font-color,...

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without JavaScript/jQuery you can use pure CSS...

```
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .changecolor:hover
            {
                background-color: Blue;
                color: Red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr class="changecolor">
                <td>
                    Hello
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works). Here's another question at Stackoverflow that shows you how to do it.

[Add background color and border to table row on hover using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688222/add-background-color-and-border-to-table-row-on-hover-using-jquery)

But here I'm putting a full example. All you need is to adapt it to render in an ASP.NET user control.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('tr').hover(function () {
                $(this).css('background-color', '#33CCFF');
            },
        function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        });
        });
    </script>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Hello world
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Goodbye world
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

All the work is done at client side.

Answer (score 2):

you can also do it only with css by creating a class for a row like below

```
    .tableRowStyle 
     {
        color: #fff;
        /* whatever style you want*/
     }

    .tableRowStyle a:hover
    {
       color: #0000ff;
       /* whatever style you want on hover */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("tr").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background","Color" );
  }, 
 function () {
  $(this).css("background","");
  }
```

);